# Python - Frequency of relationship between numerical variables on python on each row

Tags: python, relationship, frequency

I am currently trying to measure the frequency of relationship between numerical variables on each row on python. To give you an example of what I'm looking for, here is an example of data with which I work.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W80PO.png)

What I am trying to do is to measure the frequency of relationship between the value 1 and the other variables (other than 0)

I should arrive at a result like this

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3vbg.png)

If someone is able to tell me how to get the frequency of relations, it would be really appreciated

Comment: You should not put important details of the question in photos. It makes it hard for people to help you and hard for people who use screen readers. Also, you should clarify what you mean by "frequency relationship" so we don't have to infer what you mean by looking at the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly I believe that a Counter as implemented in Python’s collections module would help you. It will give you your answer in the form of a dictionary.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter